# Is the Net::HTTP Ruby gem ignoring the Content-type header in my HTTP responses?

Tags: ruby, encoding, net-http

When using the `Net::HTTP` class (Module?), I seem to have a problem that even though the response sets the Content-Type header to have charset equal to ISO-8859-1, the response's encoding is ASCII-8BIT.

I am not 100% sure why these two encodings are different, or how they are different but what I do know is that only the ISO-8859-1 encoding will let me do a transcoding into UTF-8. To wit:

```
require 'net/http'
 Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
  response = http.request request
end
response['Content-Type']
 => "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
response.body.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
response.body.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

What is going on here? If I `force_encoding` the response's body to `Encoding::ISO_8859_1`, then the transcoding works.

Is `Net::HTTP` at fault?

Comment: Are you sure that the server response is valid? Perhaps the developers of the server just did not set the right value?

Comment: The server response is valid; should have mentioned that. The body is in fact encoded as ISO-8859-1. But looks like my guess that `Net::HTTP` is by design going to assume only "arbitrary binary" as the encoding was the right one, as @frederick-cheung says in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby does not set the encoding of the response automatically (see [ticket](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2567)) and will always set the encoding to ASCII-8BIT.

That is a slightly misleading encoding name since it actually means "arbitrary binary data". This is why you need to use `force_encoding` to set the encoding before you can transcode to other encodings.